# How to delete contents of cells that only contain one character in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge Excel sheet full of customers and I am trying to find duplicates. It's challenging because sometimes people use their middle initial and other times people don't.

I want to delete only the initial (where this exists), leaving the remaining first, last etc. names within each cell in tact.

Table below illustrates:

| Raw | Modified |
| --- | --- |
| Thomas R Edward | Thomas Edward |

Comment: You can get the length of cell content with `LEN`. But are the names across a varying number of cells? Examples would make the question more clear.

Comment: Are your names in one cell or spread out across several?  One example would be helpful.  If the names are completely in a single cell, I would enable the regular expression functions in VBA as User Defined Functions and write a formula like =RegexpReplace(A1,"([^A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\.?)(?=[^A-Za-z])","").

Answer (score 0):

If the names are in one cell, one can search for the number of spaces, and use that number to identify unwanted name formats. Example formula to use:
`=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))`